# *ngFor Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the follow array in Angular inside my component:

```
pages: [
    {
        link: "link",
        name: "name",
        img: "imgPath" ,
        desc: "description"
    }, {...
```

and I am trying to use it to display a list with the follow code in the DOM:

```
    <div *ngFor="let page of pages"  class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
    <a href="{{page.link}}" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
      <div class="portfolio-hover">
        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
          <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="{{page.img}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="portfolio-caption">
      <h4>{{page.name}}</h4>
      <p class="text-muted">{{page.desc}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and I'm receiving the follow error:

zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to share more code

Comment: Try posting a live demo here https://stackblitz.com

Comment: We need more code.
Is pages within the `scope`?

Comment: Yes, it is in the scope, it is like the array was not loaded when I try to use it in the DOM

Comment: I can't found anything related to classList in your code. classList is a DOM property object to use add, remove class from DOM, so I can't found anything related classList. Can you share "zone.js" entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `pages:` to `pages=`